# tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row:0, section:0)) returns nil in spite of scrolling to top of tableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Developing an iOS application with Xcode ver 9.2, Swift.

When the RightNavigationButtonAdd is tapped, I want to insert a TableViewCell at the beginning of the TableView and focus(becomeFirstResponder) the TextField in it.

When the inserted TableViewCell is visible, it works normally. But, when the inserted TableViewCell is not visible, an error occurred because of cellForRow returns nil.

Could you tell me how to solve this problem?

```
@objc func RightNavigationButtonAdd(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    // array is ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", ...]
    array.insert("", at: 0)
    // ttableView is @IBOutlet var ttableView: UITableView!
    ttableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:0, section:0)], with: .top)
    // Scroll to top of tableView
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.ttableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row:0, section:0), at: .top, animated: true)
    }, completion: { finished in
        // when inserted cell is not visible, error occured:
        // "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
        let cell = self.ttableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row:0, section:0)) as! TableViewCell
        cell.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
        cell.textField.placeholder = "input anything ..."
    })
}
```

**Update**

I don't why, but if scroll animated: "false", it works fine!

```
@objc func RightNavigationButtonAdd(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    // array is ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", ...]
    array.insert("", at: 0)
    // ttableView is @IBOutlet var ttableView: UITableView!
    ttableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:0, section:0)], with: .top)
    // Scroll to top of tableView
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.ttableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row:0, section:0), at: .top, animated: false)
    }, completion: { finished in
        // when inserted cell is not visible, error occured:
        // "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
        let cell = self.ttableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row:0, section:0)) as! TableViewCell
        cell.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
        cell.textField.placeholder = "input anything ..."
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a cell that is visible, you should do it that way

```
let cell =  self.ttableView.visibleCells[0]
```

And then you can either check if cell exist, or check the size of self.ttableView.visibleCells, you have the choice.

So in the end

```
@objc func RightNavigationButtonAdd(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
// array is ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", ...]
array.insert("", at: 0)
// ttableView is @IBOutlet var ttableView: UITableView!
ttableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:0, section:0)], with: .top)
// Scroll to top of tableView
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
    self.ttableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row:0, section:0), at: .top, animated: true)
}, completion: { finished in
    if self.ttableView.visibleCells.count > 0 {
    let cell = self.ttableView.visibleCells[0] as! TableViewCell
    cell.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
    cell.textField.placeholder = "input anything ..."
    }
})
```

}

Comment: It might be a bug in the simulator because it may or may not occur.